# Different JDBC Driver version

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In a application I have created a oracle datsource. For this datasource I used ojdbc6.jar. When I test the datasource I am getting below information on console.

```
Database product name : Oracle
Database product version : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver
JDBC driver version  : 11.1.0.7.0-Production
```

In a second application I have created a datasource for same database with same ojdbc6.jar. But when I am testing thic datasource I am getting below information on console.

```
Database product name : Oracle
Database product version : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver
JDBC driver version  : 9.2.0.1.0
```

Why there is difference between JDBC driver version ? I am creating datasources in IBM web console.

Issue I am facing with second data source is for a select it is throwing below exception, while it works fine with first data source.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long incompatible with java.lang.String
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2768)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2905)
```

Comment: Apparently the second data source does **not** use the same jar file as the first one.

Comment: I checked this multiple times and they are using same jars. In second application there are 1 more data source which is using ojdbc14.jar. This is the only difference.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar is probably the old 9.x driver, remove that and you should be fine